# Google App Engine: using Javascript Client Library for OAuth2 authorisation

Tags: google-app-engine, file-upload, youtube-api, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to develop my first Google App Engine application in Python, as a part of which I would like users to be able to upload videos to Youtube and share them with other users of the app.  As per the recommended protocols, the upload would be to their own Youtube accounts, the only information the app would need to capture would be the video id.

I really want the facility to upload from within the app rather than redirecting users to the main Youtube site for upload so that users don't need to leave the app at any point, to keep things seamless.  I had assumed that this would be relatively straightforward, since it seems it would be a feature that a lot of websites and apps would like to offer, but it seems not.

I am really struggling to understand what OAuth2 flows I need to go through here, having never wrestled with them before.  The only upload example code in the Youtube API docs is to upload from your own machine (via command line), so not relevant here.  I've read the docs backwards, and it doesn't sound like the browser-based upload facility has been updated for the Youtube Data Api v3, so it seems the first thing I need is to get an access token from the user before using the v2 browser-based upload protocol.  Given that users will be uploading files stored locally (i.e. on their machines) through their browser, I am presuming that the client-side JavaScript OAuth2 flow is the one I need, rather than the Python server-side flow.  Or do I need both?

The issue is that I can't even get people to leave the html page I'm serving from the app using the JavaScript client library, in order to get them to the authorisation page.  To check I understand the steps to getting an access token via the JavaScript client library, I have tried as a first step literally cut-and-pasting the Google sample code into the html page from here:

[Google Api Javascript Client Library sample](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/source/browse/samples/authSample.html)

and changed the Api Key and Client Id to my own, having updated the JavaScript origins on the API Access pane on the Console and authorized Google+, but clicking the button just does nothing.

So presumably I have misunderstood something pretty fundamental here!

Any ideas? Is the issue that the JS flow is over-ridden by the control of flow from within the Python app?  Is the issue that I should actually be using the server-side flow, in which case how do I then get the user to upload from their own browser and then capture the video id once uploaded?

I can't believe I'm the first person to try this, I'd be really grateful for any pointers please if anyone has managed this already or has any ideas.  Thank you.

Comment: this might help: https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/

Comment: That's a great resource, thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option, if you're okay with handling things entirely client-side in JavaScript, and you're also okay limiting yourself to browsers that support CORS: http://apiblog.youtube.com/2012/05/unlocking-javascripts-potential-with.html That's what I'd probably go with if you're okay with those limitations and the only YouTube API integration you're doing is for uploads.

An alternative option, and one that might be more fitting for a Python App Engine application, would be to use the [server-side web application flow](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_oauth2#OAuth2_Server_Side_Web_Applications_Flow). The issue here is that you need to use a combination of the [Google APIs for Python client library](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/) to handle OAuth 2 for you, and the older [GData API Python client library](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/) to handle the browser-based upload flow. It's definitely possible to mix the two, and we have a blog post that talks about an open source Python App Engine application that does that: http://apiblog.youtube.com/2012/08/party-playlist-picker-experimental.html

There's currently no browser-based upload flow in v3, as you point out.

Comment: That is really helpful and responsive, thank you! I'm really encouraged that there is a way forward, I'm going to look into both options right now.

Comment: The CORS flow works beautifully, and really seamlessly for the user, many thanks for pointing me to it.